# Easy way to see general solution of PDE expressed in different form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I think this question should be easy and shouldn't require me to solve the entire PDE for a general solution.  Basically, how would you see immediately that the general solution of:

$$y^2 u_{xx}-2xy u_{xy}+x^2u_{yy}=y^2/x\ u_x+x^2/y \ u_x$$

Can be written as $u(x,y)=(x^2-y^2) f(x^2+y^2)+g(x^2+y^2)$ given that f and g are both arbitrary functions?

Comment: At the end of formula you should have $u_y$. Also, why would you think this "shouldn't require me to solve  for a general solution", given that the goal is to see what  the general solution is?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's supposed to be **that** easy. The thing on the left is recognizable as the result of plugging the vector $(y,-x)$ into the Hessian of $u$. This looks like the second-order tangential derivative of $u$. One has to be careful not to mistake it for $u_{\theta\theta}$ (with second derivatives, the curvature of polar coordinates gets in the way). But at least we see that polar coordinates may help here.

So, use the standard conversion formulas: 
$$u_\theta = -yu_x+xu_y$$
$$u_{\theta\theta} = y^2 u_{xx} - 2xy u_{xy} + x^2 u_{yy} - xu_x-yu_y$$
The equation takes the form
$$
u_{\theta\theta}  = \frac{y^2}{x} u_x + \frac{x^2}{y} u_y - xu_x-yu_y
$$
which simplifies to 
$$
u_{\theta\theta}  = - u_\theta \cot 2\theta  
$$
This ODE can be solved, producing $A+B\cos 2\theta$. The  constants $A,B$ can depend on $r$ in any way.